# Bootstrap 5.0 columns number even (4-2-1)

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

i'm trying to set to my bootstrap row a number even of columns 4 or 2 or 1.
Actually when i resize the width of my browser, the number of columns start at 4 then 3, 2 and at the end 1.
There is a method that resize the number of columns from 4 to 2 without passing to 3?

```
 ...
  <div class="row row-cols-2">
      <div class="col-sm">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        ...
      </div>
  </div>
 ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use the `row-cols-*` responsively..

```
   <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4">
        <div class="col"> ... </div>
        <div class="col"> ... </div>
        <div class="col"> ... </div>
        <div class="col"> ... </div>
   </div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/6oMOdDrZIh)